# how to send data from kafka topic 1 to topic 2 with logstash?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper

I want to sent data from topic1 to topic 2 with logstash,but I don't see data in topic 2
my config in logstash :

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    topics => "topic1"
    consumer_threads => 12
    group_id => mygroup
    codec => json
    type => "json"
    decorate_events => true
  }
}

output {
        kafka {
          codec => json
          topic_id => "topic2"
          bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"

       }
```

Comment: Can you share the logstash logs with us ? 
I see that a } is missing at the end of file but i suppose this is due to copy and past